# why h2o.ai use self implements DKV instead of redis like kv store?

Tags: h2o

the h2o DKV dose not have persisting to disk support, if the cluster crashed it cannot restore the frames and data, so why they use it, is it possible to replace the DKV to redis?

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the question is very subjective (work on H2O started when Redis was very young, we use highly optimized DKV for our needs for which Redis would most probably be slower, having everything in the JVM is much easier and faster than using an outside database which cannot be embedded easily within the JVM because its written in C etc.etc.).

As for the second part - because of certain reasons (some of them pointed out above) you cannot use other data stores.

All that being said, H2O Frames **can** be saved to disk, though (`exportFile` in R, `export_file` in Python, there are also ways to do it in Java/Scala), as CSV files, which can be imported after a crash. Similarly models can be saved and loaded at any time. You can resume training or restart with new data using those models as your checkpoints.

Comment: yes, frames and models can be saved to disk，but not automatically,  each restart of the cluster will lost everything

Comment: This can be done in literally few lines of code, if we had such a feature in H2O you'd probably have to configure it and would take similar amount of work. Leaving this to the user indeed makes the user write more code but imho is a much more robust solution than anything we could come up with.

The only use case I could see where it would be better to have this as part of H2O is to implement it as a JVM shutdown hook, but you can implement it yourself if you're using Java/Scala version but need to remember it might not work 100% of the times depending on the type of shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

H2O was designed to be an in-memory system. It was designed with speed and scaling to large data in mind, not high-availability.

Persistence to disk would come with trade-offs against those primary design goals (or, at least, an increase in code complexity which can lower reliability and/or increase developer costs).

I'd love to see some high-availability features, and have plenty of ideas. E.g. every 10 minutes all threads are paused and each machine dumps its entire memory to disk, which could then be restored from very quickly. 15 seconds every 10 minutes won't be a major slowdown.

But I think the bottom-line is that H2O doesn't crash often enough for this to ever become a high enough priority.  As it is open source, maybe one day someone with that itch will come and scratch it.

Comment: dose h2o have  Resource isolation or multi-tenant support?

Comment: @寒江雪 no, the intended use case is to have an instance per user